# Kotlin convert doesn't work anymore for Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Before AS3.0, I could paste Java code and this would be translated into Kotlin automagically with a popup asking me. Now this doesn't work anymore. Also using the shortcut:

"Main menu", "Code", "Convert Java File to Kotlin File"

doesn't work.

Things I've tried:
- "File", "Invalidate Cache / Restart"
- I have the kotlin plugin installed (in 3.0 this should be by default)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

When I copy-paste

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

It **does** come up with the convertor popup. And when I paste

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

Right after this, it actually does work. But when I **first** paste

```
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

then it doesn't work?

Comment: Is the convert option greyed when you have a Java file open in the editor?

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, then it is not greyed out.

Comment: Did you try the shortcut `ctrl+alt+shift+k`?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I think I had a problem with hidden chars in the copied code. Pasting it into Sublime editor first removed these and then it worked I think.

Answer (score 1):

Please show which code you're pasting. In order for the converter to run, the code you paste must be a valid Java expression, method or class.
I think that can be problem..
or

The problem occurs if you insert Java code without the "import" section - then the converter does not know that the convertible method needs to be overloaded.